# How should I model my data(multi-category, multi-level) for django-haystack?

Tags: django, database-design, solr, schema, django-haystack

I'll give an example of data.
(purely for demonstration, I don't know much about car)

Top category,

```
Car, Computer, Shoes, ..
```

Car has many facets.(sub category)

```
Car - 2 door/4 door  
Car - Audi/Bmw/..
```

Sub category can have another sub category.

```
Audi - A series/S series/R series
```

Now, product can have multiple parents.

```
Audi A4 -child of- A series - Audi - Car 
Audi A4 -child of- 4 door  - Car (one shorter depth)
```

How would I model this in DB?

I've looked at a few RDBMS-only approaches for searching capability, and it looks awful to maintain.
I'm looking at django-haystack, solr approach.
But still I need to model this in django's models.py.

How would I do this and make a search index for haystack?

I'm new to whole django/haystack/solr.
I looked at solr's example document.
It looks like each item has all the necessary data in it.(I guess people call it flattened-data?)

Can I somehow separate meta-data(category trees) from data(actual product item) in DB?
I just feel that's the right approach, am I wrong?

- EDIT

I forgot to mention that I'd like to use solr's faceted search capability.
So after modeling it in DB, how would my search_indexes.py look like for haystack?

Comment: Check this [answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318758/279564) mentioning subtypes & supertypes.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things.

One is you want to store multiple properties for an item. For this, if you want to use a relational database use the [entity-attribute-value pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model). [eav-django](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/eav-django/1.0.2) provides this implementation for django.

However, a more flexible (and less cumbersome) approach would be to use a document database (like couch) or other NoSQL solutions. These provide a flexible schema so you don't have to worry about how many "properties" or "meta-data" you have to store about a particular object/item.

The other part of your question is maintaining a tree of relationships with *n*-depth. This is implemented using the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT) (also called modified pre-order tree traversal). Like eav, there is [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't completely grasp EAV, but it looked hell complex to maintain, and nested set model doesn't seem to support multiple parents(categories). Then I found solr faceted search is capable of doing what I want. Hoever as I mentioned in the post, solr example has all the meta-data and data in a single file. I'd like to separate meta-data from data and store them in DB, and at the same time use solr faceted search capability.   I hope it makes sense.